# Does IHttpModule module work with WCF service,

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, iis, ihttpmodule

I have WCF service. i want each and request to WCF operation be scanned throughthe IHttpModule module. But it not hitting the IHttpModule.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

HttpModules work with WCF only if you run WCF service in ASP.NET compatibility mode. You can enable ASP.NET compatibility mode either of following way.

1. Using web.config

   < system.serviceModel>
   < serviceHostingEnvironment 
                              aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
   < /system.serviceModel>

2. Using attribute

   [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = 
   AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
   public class Service : IService
   {
   // ...
   }

Comment: Is there any other way that i can scan the input parameters is don't run in Asp.net compatibility mode.

Comment: If you don't like option of compatibility mode then you can explore IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.afterreceiverequest(v=vs.110).aspx